# use an array to assign values to list box

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

I am Trying to use array to assign movie titles to list box. They select the movie in the drop down list then it shows up in the list box (this does not work) using C# and aspx

```
  protected void addToCartImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
  {

    string [] movieNameArray = new string [10];

    movieNameArray[0] = "The Advengers";
    movieNameArray[1] = "Titanic";
    movieNameArray[2] = "Frozen";
    movieNameArray[3] = "Boy";
    movieNameArray[4] = "Grown Ups";
    movieNameArray[5] = "Coach Carter";
    movieNameArray[6] = "More than a game";
    movieNameArray[7] = "Harry Potter";
    movieNameArray[8] = "Avatar";
    movieNameArray[9] = "Titanic";



    cartListBox.Items.Add(movieNameArray.ToString());
    DropDownList3.Items.Add(movieNameArray.ToString());

}
```

Comment: It would be better if you asked a question in the form of a question and not a statement about what you hope to achieve.

Comment: But what is your exact question? I dont see any question here. Please if you are asking something then ask it properly with proper details.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind your dropdown to the array. I.e. Instead of

```
DropDownList3.Items.Add(movieNameArray.ToString());
```

Use

```
DropDownList3.DataSource = movieNameArray;
DropDownList3.DataBind();
```